How to Set Connection Pool Size for a Quarkus REST Client Programmatically?
I'm working on a Quarkus project where I need to create a REST client programmatically using QuarkusRestClientBuilder. While using the annotated client (@RegisterRestClient), I know that the connection pool size can be configured via properties like quarkus.rest-client.connection-pool-size. However, I haven't found a way to set this property for my Rest Clients when building them programmatically.
Here's a simplified version of my current code:
SomeRestClient client =
    QuarkusRestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .baseUri(new URI(baseUrl))
        .proxyAddress("some-proxy-address", 80)
        .build(SomeRestClient.class);


You need to do something this:
Client client = QuarkusRestClientBuilder.newBuilder().baseUri(uri)
                .property(QuarkusRestClientProperties.CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE, 20)
                .build(Client.class);


QuarkusRestClientBuilder also lets us set HttpClientOptions like this:
HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions();
options.setsetMaxPoolSize(5);
QuarkusRestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
.baseUri(URI.create("https://stage.code.quarkus.io/api"))
.httpClientOptions(options);
Your property approach and this approach work the same behind the scenes, or there's some difference?

It essentially does the same thing
